# Foundation and smoothstate doesn't open reveal modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm using [FoundationPress](https://github.com/olefredrik/FoundationPress) and [smoothstate](https://github.com/miguel-perez/smoothState.js) on my WordPress page. Now on mobile, I created a menu using hamburgers and reveal modal and works fine but after clicking on something, the menu won't open anymore. I think this is because of the smoothstate.js not reloading the script.

As an option of the smoothstate, I have this script:

```
onAfter: function($container, $newContent) {
            $( "#ham" ).click(function() {
                $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active"); //you can list several class names
                $('#abnavmodal').foundation('toggle');
                event.preventDefault();
            });
```

Here's my [website](http://ableslayer.com/). Note that the menu only appears on mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the script by changing to the new [Foundation 6 programmatic use plugin declaration](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/javascript.html#programmatic-use)

Here's my final script:

```
onAfter: function($container, $newContent) {

            var $modal = new Foundation.Reveal($('#abnavmodal'), {
              animationIn: 'slide-in-left',
              animationOut: 'slide-out-left'
            });

            // Hamburgers
            $( "#ham" ).click(function() {
                $(".hamburger").toggleClass("is-active"); //you can list several class names
                $modal.toggle();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
});
```